# Best way to define a MySQL relationship

Tags: php, mysql, database, many-to-many

I'd like to create something like this:

A users table, a address table, and a posts table.

A user can have a single address, but can have multiple posts. This would require a mysql many-to-many relationship, correct? And how should i tie them all together? An example would be great. Thanks!

Comment: the relationship between `user` and `posts` is one-to-many, and between `address` and `user`, one-to-one.  Join them with ID columns in the tables

Answer (score 2):

```
users table
-----------
id      PK
name


posts table
-----------
id       PK
user_id  FK
title


address table
-------------
id        PK
user_id   FK
city
```

PK = Primary Key
FK = Foreign Key

To select all posts of a specific user you can do

```
select p.*
from posts p
inner join users u on u.id = p.user_id
where u.name = 'tom'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Going to try this and see if it fits. Could you please provide a select query for the example you posted? -- Andrei

Comment: You don't need the user_post table. You have a one-2-many and not a many-to-many correct? Meaning you don't have multiple users for the same post right?